# не получается вызвать django-admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

пытаюсь научиться джанго, вроде установил его через pip, даже могу весрию проверить и все равно выдает такую ошибку. не пойму в чем дело(в обычной командной строке, pycharm тоже самое выдает)
[image: ошибка]

Comment: Видимо при установке питона забыли поставить галочку добавления в PATH, так что теперь пишите полный путь к django-admin в Program Files

Comment: спасибо, полностью переустановил python с указанием галочки и помогло